# Discrepancy between Ruby version and Gemfile Ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gemfile

If I boot Aptana to begin a new rails app, and go to do `rails new app`, it tells me there is a discrepancy between my ruby version and the ruby version in my gemfile. Which gemfile is that referring to? I haven't been able to initiate the `rails new` command. Where do I need to change that setting? I am on a Windows machine.

By the way, this issue first arose when I did a git pull for a rails app. Somehow my machine's ruby version was overridden by the ruby version in the gemfile of that app. But even when I change it in the gemfile of that app it still keeps telling me that I'm running a different version of Ruby than is listed in the gemfile. So something is overridden somewhere else. Even when I reboot, restart, use a different root directory, etc, I still run into the same issue.

Comment: Can you please provide the command line output in question?

Comment: You can use `bundle exec` before each command to use gem version from gemfile.

Comment: If I run any command at all pretty much, I get this output:
'Your Ruby version is 2.1.7, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.1'

Comment: My question is, where is my Gemfile set to 2.1.1? If I can't even get as far as to instantiate a new rails app, where is it seeing that Gemfile? And to clarify further, even after I physically updated the Gemfile that originally caused the conflict, it's still telling me my Gemfile is set to 2.1.1. Where is it reading that from?

Comment: $ rails new bda
Your Ruby version is 2.1.7, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.1'